# Related to probability : Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

I was solving this problem:

For a group of 7 people, find the probability that all 4 seasons (winter, spring, summer,
fall) occur at least once each among their birthdays, assuming that all seasons are equally
likely.

I arrived at the answer: 1 - [4*(3/4)^7 + 6*(2/4)^7 + 4*(1/4)^7].

But the original answer is : 1 - [4*(3/4)^7 - 6*(2/4)^7 + 4*(1/4)^7], and i'm not able to understand why there is a negative sign before the 6*(2/4)^7. Please enlighten me ?

Comment: Do you understand the negative sign in expressions like $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ and $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$?

Comment: ..and then the alternating signs when you have more than two sets involved....?

Comment: I think I have to review sets. Thank you though.

Comment: @Bbashwar Sengupta Do you mind explaining how you arrived at your solution?